# Grab all artifacts from gitlab-ci dir and make them an artifact

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am trying to display all the artifacts `.html` files in a specific directory:
`$TOOLS_PATH/terraform_results/html` that are generated during a build job stage when my gitlab pipeline is run.

when this is run in the `gitlab` pipeline I get a warning:
`Uploading artifacts... WARNING: tools/terraform_results/html/*: no matching files`

I'm invoking this via gitlab-ci.yml file via:

```
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - "$TOOLS_PATH/terraform_results/html/*"
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: just following up, did you solve this issue. If so, please select an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Drop the quotes and wildcard, and indent the `paths` list. This will zip everything in the `html` folder. You can use wildcards like `*.html` to filter filenames if needed:

```yaml
artifacts:
    paths:
      - $TOOLS_PATH/terraform_results/html/
```

If that doesn't work, read the gitlab-ci.yml reference on [artifacts:paths](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#artifactspaths) to make sure you didn't miss anything. For example:

> Paths are relative to the project directory ($CI_PROJECT_DIR) and can’t directly link outside it.

Make sure the `tools` directory is located in the root of your project directory. You can confirm the directory exists by adding `ls $CI_PROJECT_DIR` to your `scripts` section and checking the runner logs.

Answer (score 1):

For `.html` only files

```
artifacts:
  paths:
    - $TOOLS_PATH/terraform_results/html/*.html
```